# Set DataType in Excel Cell using OfficeOpenXml in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the OfficeOpenXml library to create Excel files in C#. Specifically, I need to set the datatype of a specific cell to EUR programmatically. For example 1234.5 must be turned into 1234.5 €.

With the UI, this operation is fairly easy RightClick -->Format Cells --> Number --> Currency --> Symbol  (see attached image). [image].

Below is my code. Any clue on how to do that?

```
string fullpath = @"\\SOME_PATH\test_file.xlsx";

// if file exists, overwrite
if (File.Exists(fullpath))
    File.Delete(fullpath);

var pck = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(fullpath));

var workSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("contract summary");

workSheet.Cell(1, 1).DataType = "Currency"; // this does not work.

workSheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = 1234.5.ToString();
```

Comment: Currency is not an Excel datatype it is an Excel format - does not affect the cells's value only the way it is displayed on the screen.

Comment: Thank you @Charles, do you know if this property is accessible using C#?

Comment: sorry - I am not familiar with using the OpenXML library. Look for either Format or Style.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is

```
workSheet.Cells[1,1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00 €";
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following code, and it successfully creates a custom format with the `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` library.

```
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].NumberFormat = "#,###,###.00 €";
```

I believe it can also be used on columns, rows, or groups of cells.

I'm not sure how similar `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` is to `OpenOfficeXML`, but I hope that can at least point you in the right direction.